# How to fix Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = text

Tags: laravel, postgresql

```php
$rows = DB::table($table)->select('content.id as product_id', 'content.title as product_title', 'custom_fields.name as price_name', 'custom_fields.name_key as price_key', 'custom_fields_values.value as price')
      ->leftJoin('custom_fields', 'content.id', '=', 'custom_fields.rel_id')
      ->leftJoin('custom_fields_values', 'custom_fields.id', '=', 'custom_fields_values.custom_field_id')
      ->where('content.content_type', '=', 'product')
      ->where('content.is_deleted', '=', 0)
      ->where('custom_fields.type', '=', 'price')
      ->get()
      ->toArray();
```

Comment: You're trying to compare an integer with a text field in one or more of your `where` clauses and PostgreSQL doesn't automatically type cast as of its later versions. I'm not sure which one is throwing the error out of the three, can you tell us what the types of each field are? Is `content.is_deleted` a text field?

Comment: i want to join between content.id and custom_fields.rel_id and in table "content" i have store "id" as integer and in table "custom_fields" i have store "rel_id" as text field

Comment: when i use this it work well but how can i use it with laravel query? Help me please.

**$books = \DB::select("SELECT book_content.id as product_id, book_content.title as product_title, book_custom_fields.name as price_name, book_custom_fields.name_key as price_key 
                         FROM book_content LEFT JOIN book_custom_fields ON book_content.id::text = book_custom_fields.rel_id ");**

Comment: Please update your question instead of putting extra code in comments. Put a description for your problem as well in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query which you've mentioned in the comment like this in Laravel

```
DB::table('book_content')
    ->leftJoin('book_custom_fields','book_content.id','=','book_custom_fields.rel_id')
    ->select('book_content.id as product_id','book_content.title as product_title', 'book_custom_fields.name as price_name', 'book_custom_fields.name_key as price_key')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Let me know if it is helpful or not.

Comment: Please explain why this is expected to solve OP problem

Comment: this one it work as well ** $row = \DB::select("SELECT book_content.id as product_id, book_content.title as product_title, book_custom_fields.name as price_name, book_custom_fields.name_key as price_key 
//                          FROM book_content LEFT JOIN book_custom_fields ON book_content.id::text = book_custom_fields.rel_id "); ** 

but how to convert like this **book_content.id::text** in laravel query?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you're storing `custom_fields.rel_id` as a text as opposed to an integer? If it's a string ID e.g. `A2BFZJ`, why would you compare it to `content.id` which is of type integer. Also if you used Models that Laravel provides this could be solved using the `$casts` array within the Model.

The only other way to type cast in Laravel query is simply using DB::raw, you can type cast as follows:

```
->where(DB::raw('CAST(content.content_type AS TEXT)'), '=', 'product');
```